# How many people own monero?

Tags: monero-community

(Sept 2016) 
Obviously I'm looking for some thumb in the air estimates as this isn't a 'knowable' figure.  If we look on say the reddit it has ~5800 subscribers which gives us a rough ballpark for the community.  Is there anything other smart way to guesstimate it?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an analysis I did of the monero thread on bitcointalk in May 2016:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=583449.msg14785207#msg14785207

You have to figure that the number of posters/subscribers/users has gone up significantly in the last month or so though.